# JQuery UI Sortable - restrict drag area of an html sortable element to a specific child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

This is my simplified div structure on which i applied the JQuery UI sortable interaction (see [this JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ngKMC/10/)):

```
<div id="sortable_panels">
    <div class="panel" id="panel1">
        <div class="header" id="panel1_header">Panel 1 header</div>
        <div id="panel1_content"></div>                    
    </div>    
    <div class="panel" id="panel2">
        <div class="header" id="panel2_header">Panel 2 header</div>
        <div id="panel2_content"></div>                    
    </div>    
    <div class="panel" id="panel3">
        <div class="header" id="panel3_header">Panel 3 header</div>
        <div id="panel3_content"></div>                    
    </div>    
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>​
```

I want a panel to be draggable only when I drag the panel headers. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Like that? http://jsfiddle.net/aRczV/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use this option in your sortable interaction

```
handle:'.header'
```